# Why does web3j and javascript keccak256 return different hashes if '0x' is at the start of the string?

Tags: web3j, keccak, sha3

We are trying to build a merkle tree in web3j and put the root for verification into the smart contract.  Due to this problem we can't generate the same route between web3j and solidity/js...

In javascript:

```
Buffer.from(keccak256('4cdecb9e5f6a88b1696ca7e28b3a7e3d7474058d')).toString('hex');
Buffer.from(keccak256('0x4cdecb9e5f6a88b1696ca7e28b3a7e3d7474058d')).toString('hex');
```

Gives:

07c50cf7885d2f22d0ebc2b0e03eaf1f51d453169eddd2205970b9c139ec9475
**47413ead80d195beca855e500674fd1a0a70c2f51bb3e82043c82959cd43d1c8**

In web3j:

```
Numeric.toHexString(Hash.sha3("4cdecb9e5f6a88b1696ca7e28b3a7e3d7474058d".getBytes()), 0, 40, false);
Numeric.toHexString(Hash.sha3("0x4cdecb9e5f6a88b1696ca7e28b3a7e3d7474058d".getBytes()), 0, 42, false);
```

Gives:

07c50cf7885d2f22d0ebc2b0e03eaf1f51d453169eddd2205970b9c139ec9475
**0652712e0f4e9f734d7a1e1a47413791135ed765dd25779c0eb5a282e0739c6e**

The first result is the same, the 2nd different.  This seems to be so with anything having '0x' at the front - regardless of string length, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the concept of **how a hash generates**. You will obviously get entirly different wallet address by just changing one alphabet in your private key.

**Sha3** is exactly doing what it has to do, it generates a hash to a given address.

Don't get distracted by `0x` it just represents that this hash belongs to the Ethereum network. `0x` is not generated by **sha3**, you have to add it your self and while validating you will yourself have to remove it from the start.